# Does YouTube API forbid to download video captions if you are not it's owner?

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

As it seems to me, YouTube API [forbids](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions?hl=en) to download video captions if you're not it's owner:

> Captions for a video can **only** be created, **retrieved**, modified and deleted **by the owner of that video**.

The link above leads to documentation of YouTube API v2.0, which is deprecated, but it seems that in v3.0 this policy remains the same. If you [try](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download) to download captions of a video, you'll get [the following 403-error](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download#errors):

> The permissions associated with the request are not sufficient to download the caption track. The request might not be properly authorized, or the video order might not have enabled third-party contributions for this caption.

---

At the same time you need only API_KEY to [list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list) captions of any YouTube video without any authorization (instantiating YouTube object as in this [official example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#search_by_keyword)):

```
youtube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
        new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request)
                throws IOException {
            }
        }).setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-search-sample").build();

CaptionListResponse captionListResponse = youtube
    .captions()
    .list("snippet", "jNhtbmXzIaM")
    .setKey(API_KEY)
    .execute();

List<Caption> captions = captionListResponse.getItems();
CaptionSnippet snippet;
for (Caption caption : captions) {
    snippet = caption.getSnippet();
    System.out.println("ID: " + caption.getId());
    System.out.println("Name: " + snippet.getName());
    System.out.println("Language: " + snippet.getLanguage());
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

So does YouTube API v3.0 really restrict read access to captions while it's public data and there are even [services](http://keepsubs.com/) and [scripts](https://github.com/joshlarsen/yt-captions) allowing you to download captions of any YouTube video? How captions of any youtube video can be fetched (solutions via using API preferred)?

Comment: Currently, I believe only the owner of a video can download the captions, but others can download captions for public videos provided the owner has enabled third-party contributions for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70756998

Comment: @not_a_bot So why do sites like `downsub` still work and download subtitles of any youtube video?

Comment: @NamLee because they scrape the html of the video page. The caption url is somewhere in there