# Get YouTube captions

Tags: javascript, java, video, youtube-api, video.js

How can programmatically get subtitles of a playing YouTube video?

Initially I've tried to do it offline via [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/), but [as it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033153/does-youtube-api-forbid-to-download-video-captions-if-you-are-not-its-owner) YouTube forbids to fetch subtitles of videos you are not the owner.

Now I'm trying to do it online. I haven't found [YouTube Player Api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) methods for captions, also I've tried to get YouTube captions as TextTrack with [videojs](http://www.videojs.com/) player in [the way it could be done for usual videos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32045281/3084258), but the following doesn't work:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/youtube.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<video  id="myvideo"
        class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" 
        controls 
        preload="auto" 
        width="640" 
        height="360">
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myvideo = videojs(
        "myvideo",
        {
            "techOrder": ["youtube"],
            "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNhtbmXzIaM" 
        },
        function() {
            console.log('Tracks: ' + this.textTracks().length); //zero here :(

            /*var aTextTrack = this.textTracks()[0];
            aTextTrack.on('loaded', function() {
                console.log('here it is');
                cues = aTextTrack.cues();
                console.log('Ready State', aTextTrack.readyState()) 
                console.log('Cues', cues);
            });
            aTextTrack.show();*/
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried an ugly solution with parsing YouTube Player IFrame (there is a div inside it with current subtitles' line), but it doesn't work because of origin mismatch security issues.

---

Is there any way my goal can be achieved in java (for offline solutions) or javascript (for online solutions)?

Comment: I don't really know much about the YouTube API and I know this is a Ruby and not a Java solution, but hopefully, [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/joshlarsen/yt-captions) can lead you in the right direction.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46864428/how-do-some-sites-download-youtube-captions for an offline option (youtube-dl)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**THIS SOLUTION STOPPED WORKING**

UPDATES: The URL from Google stopped working. This approach is paused at the moment.

Solution:
How I managed to get the captions from a youtube video is by making a simple request to this url [https://video.google.com/timedtext?lang={LANG}&v={videoId}](https://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=%7BLANG%7D&v=%7BvideoId%7D)

I have tried to use the Youtube API v3 but at the moment it doesn't work. When you do a request with the Youtube API v3 on a certain video you need that the person which uploaded the video to approve the caption's download, if not you'll have a 403 error in the console. It's normal to have the error, the server doesn't receive the approval so it returns an error.

You can download the captions from your own video with the Youtube API v3.

Something similar to this will do the job. The response will come in an XML format:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=en&v=5MgBikgcWnY"
    }).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).fail(function (response) {
        console.log();
    });
```

Comment: This is great! I expanded on this below.

Comment: This doesn't work for all video ID's for some reason e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjbMqU-3mYE

Comment: If the video doesn't have captions it will not work.

Comment: If the video has auto-generated captions, likewise, it will not work

Comment: stopped working in 2021

Comment: I'll carry on with some investigations, but as it seems, it stopped working.

Answer (score 8):

Building on Sergiu Mare's suggestion, I wrote an encapsulated function that can return the captions in the console.

This is written in pure JavaScript (ES6) and you can test it out below, or you can copy everything below and paste it in the console of any video that has captions.

---

## Updated version

### OOP approach

```js
const main = async () => {
  const
    defaultId = 'fJ9rUzIMcZQ', /* Queen – Bohemian Rhapsody */
    json = await YouTubeCaptionUtil
      .fetchCaptions(YouTubeCaptionUtil.videoId() || defaultId),
    csv = CsvUtil.fromJson(json);
  console.log(csv);
};

class YouTubeCaptionUtil {
  static async fetchCaptions(videoId, options) {
    const
      opts = { ...YouTubeCaptionUtil.defaultOptions, ...options },
      response = await fetch(YouTubeCaptionUtil.__requestUrl(videoId, opts)),
      json = await response.json();
    return YouTubeCaptionUtil.__parseTranscript(json);
  }
  static videoId() {
    const video_id = window.location.search.split('v=')[1];
    if (video_id != null) {
      const ampersandPosition = video_id.indexOf('&');
      if (ampersandPosition != -1) {
        return video_id.substring(0, ampersandPosition);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
  static __requestUrl(videoId, { baseUrl, languageId }) {
    return `${baseUrl}?lang=${languageId}&v=${videoId}&fmt=json3`;
  }
  static __parseTranscript({events}) {
    return events.map(({tStartMs, dDurationMs, segs: [{utf8}]}) => ({
      start: YouTubeCaptionUtil.__formatTime(tStartMs),
      dur: YouTubeCaptionUtil.__formatTime(dDurationMs),
      text: utf8
    }));
  }
  static __formatTime(seconds) {
    const date = new Date(null);
    date.setSeconds(seconds);
    return date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
  };
}
YouTubeCaptionUtil.defaultOptions = {
  baseUrl: 'https://video.google.com/timedtext',
  languageId: 'en'
};

class CsvUtil {
  static fromJson(json, options) {
    const
      opts = { ...CsvUtil.defaultOptions, ...options },
      keys = Object.keys(json[0]).filter(key =>
        opts.ignoreKeys.indexOf(key) === -1),
      lines = [];
    if (opts.includeHeader) lines.push(keys.join(opts.delimiter));
    return lines.concat(json
        .map(entry => keys.map(key => entry[key]).join(opts.delimiter)))
        .join('\n');
  }
}
CsvUtil.defaultOptions = {
  includeHeader: false,
  ignoreKeys: ['dur'],
  delimiter: '\t'
};

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Functional approach

```js
const main = async() => {
  const defaultId = 'fJ9rUzIMcZQ'; // Queen – Bohemian Rhapsody (default ID)
  const json = await loadYouTubeSubtitles(getYouTubeVideoId() || defaultId);
  const csv = jsonToCsv(json, {
    includeHeader: false,
    ignoreKeys: ['dur'],
    delimiter: '\t',
  });

  console.log(csv);
};

const parseTranscript = ({ events }) => {
  return events.map(({ tStartMs, dDurationMs, segs: [{ utf8 }] }) => ({
    start: formatTime(tStartMs),
    dur: formatTime(dDurationMs),
    text: utf8
  }));
};

const formatTime = (seconds) => {
  let date = new Date(null);
  date.setSeconds(seconds);
  return date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
};

const getYouTubeVideoId = () => {
  var video_id = window.location.search.split('v=')[1];
  if (video_id != null) {
    var ampersandPosition = video_id.indexOf('&');
    if (ampersandPosition != -1) {
      return video_id.substring(0, ampersandPosition);
    }
  }
  return null;
};

const loadYouTubeSubtitles = async(videoId, options) => {
  options = Object.assign({
    baseUrl: 'https://video.google.com/timedtext',
    languageId: 'en',
  }, options || {});

  const requestUrl = `${options.baseUrl}?lang=${options.languageId}&v=${videoId}&fmt=json3`;
  const response = await fetch(requestUrl);
  const json = await response.json();

  return parseTranscript(json);
};

const jsonToCsv = (json, options) => {
  options = Object.assign({
    includeHeader: true,
    delimiter: ',',
    ignoreKeys: []
  }, options || {});
  let keys = Object.keys(json[0]).filter(key => options.ignoreKeys.indexOf(key) === -1);
  let lines = [];
  if (options.includeHeader) {
    lines.push(keys.join(options.delimiter));
  }
  return lines.concat(json
      .map(entry => keys.map(key => entry[key]).join(options.delimiter)))
    .join('\n');
};

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

## Original response

This response creates an `XMLHttpRequest`.

```js
loadYouTubeSubtitles((getYouTubeVideoId() || 'fJ9rUzIMcZQ'), {
  callbackFn : function(json) {
    console.log(jsonToCsv(json, {
      includeHeader : false,
      ignoreKeys : [ 'dur' ],
      delimiter : '\t',
    }));
  }
}); // Queen – Bohemian Rhapsody (default ID)

function getYouTubeVideoId() {
  var video_id = window.location.search.split('v=')[1];
  if (video_id != null) {
    var ampersandPosition = video_id.indexOf('&');
    if (ampersandPosition != -1) {
      return video_id.substring(0, ampersandPosition);
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function loadYouTubeSubtitles(videoId, options) {
  options = Object.assign({
    baseUrl : 'https://video.google.com/timedtext',
    languageId : 'en',
    callbackFn : function(json) { console.log(json); } // Default
  }, options || {});

  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609450/1762224
  var decodeHTML = (function() {
    let el = document.createElement('div');
    function __decode(str) {
      if (str && typeof str === 'string') {
        str = str.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi, '')
          .replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '');
        el.innerHTML = str;
        str = el.textContent;
        el.textContent = '';
      }
      return str;
    }
    removeElement(el); // Clean-up
    return __decode;
  })();
  
  function removeElement(el) {
    el && el.parentNode && el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  }

  function parseTranscriptAsJSON(xml) {
    return [].slice.call(xml.querySelectorAll('transcript text'))
      .map(text => ({
        start : formatTime(Math.floor(text.getAttribute('start'))),
        dur : formatTime(Math.floor(text.getAttribute('dur'))),
        text : decodeHTML(text.textContent).replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
      }));
  }

  function formatTime(seconds) {
    let date = new Date(null);
    date.setSeconds(seconds);
    return date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
  }

  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', `${options.baseUrl}?lang=${options.languageId}&v=${videoId}`, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'document';
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
      options.callbackFn(parseTranscriptAsJSON(this.response));
    } else {
      console.log('Error: ' + this.status);
    }
  };
  xhr.onerror = function() {
    console.log('Error!');
  };
  xhr.send();
}

function jsonToCsv(json, options) {
  options = Object.assign({
    includeHeader : true,
    delimiter : ',',
    ignoreKeys : []
  }, options || {});
  let keys = Object.keys(json[0]).filter(key => options.ignoreKeys.indexOf(key) === -1);
  let lines = [];
  if (options.includeHeader) { lines.push(keys.join(options.delimiter)); }
  return lines.concat(json
    .map(entry => keys.map(key => entry[key]).join(options.delimiter)))
    .join('\n');
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: as of now 11 Dec 2021 this no longer work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @tonnoz I think YouTube recently changed their API to require OAuth or something, see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list

Answer (score 8):

**The following works when you're on the youtube page**
Open the developer console. Try copy paste this: (make sure to refresh your page!)

```
let subsUrl = ytInitialPlayerResponse.captions.playerCaptionsTracklistRenderer.captionTracks[0].baseUrl;
let subs = await (await fetch(subsUrl)).text();
let xml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(subs,"text/xml");
let textNodes = [...xml.getElementsByTagName('text')];
let subsText = textNodes.map(x => x.textContent).join("\n").replaceAll('&#39;',"'");
console.log(subsText);
```

Wow, isn't that cool? And short and simple as well?

This is possible because of a really cool trick: on a youtube page there is a global variable `ytInitialPlayerResponse` with a link to the captions:  (make sure to refresh the page first)

```
let subsUrl = ytInitialPlayerResponse.captions.playerCaptionsTracklistRenderer.captionTracks[0].baseUrl;
```

Because you're on the YouTube page, you are allowed to fetch this url (no cors problem, because your fetch originates from youtube.com)

```
let subs = await (await fetch(subsUrl)).text();
```

This text should be parsed as xml. For this it's very useful to use the DOMParser:

```
let xml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(subs,"text/xml");
```

You then want to get the text elements

```
xml.getElementsByTagName('text')
```

With spread notation you can make it an array of text nodes

```
let textNodes = [...xml.getElementsByTagName('text')]
```

On which you can perform a map operation to get the parameters. We are interested in textContent:

```
textNodes.map(x => x.textContent)
```

Now you have an array of subtitles.
To join this to one big text you can write the following:

```
let subsText = textNodes.map(x => x.textContent).join("\n").replaceAll('&#39;',"'");
```

Note that ' is a notation for ' in the youtube subtitle, so we replace that.

In Chrome's developers' console you have to add console.log the thing to get rid of `\n` notation, so you write:

```
console.log(subsText)
```

**How to download the subtitles**
If you want to automatically download a txt file you could add this code from this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server):

```
function downloadText(filename, text) {
  var el = document.createElement('a');
  el.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  el.setAttribute('download', filename);
  el.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.click();
  document.body.removeChild(el);
}

downloadText('subs.txt',subsText);
```

PS: I'm using let, not const so that you can copy paste it multiple times to the same console
PS2: This example uses the first baseUrl, nice exercise: try to find other languages!

Have fun with it!

Comment: If you want to find a certain language, use this: `let getBaseUrl = (langCode) => ytInitialPlayerResponse.captions.playerCaptionsTracklistRenderer.captionTracks.find(x => x.vssId.indexOf("." + langCode) === 0)?.baseUrl` and replace the subsUrl with `getBaseUrl('en')` for example

Answer (score -1):

You probably do not need to download it directly from youtube, there are web services you can manipulate.

For example you could go to http://keepsubs.com/?url=insert_youtube_url here and download the captions from the site via the link found in this CSS path for english subtitles:

```
#dl > a:nth-child(2)
```

You could do this in javascript using the following method:

```
function myFunction(url_to_download){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://keepsubs.com/?url=" + url_to_download, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    var fake_html = document.createElement("div");
    fake_html.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', xmlHttp.responseText);
    var url = fake_html.querySelector("#dl > a:nth-child(2)");

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", url.href, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );

    console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
myFunction("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ");
```

Basically, this method visits KeepSubs, finds the text download url, gets the text in the file at the url and outputs it to the console.

Keep in mind that although this is one way to do it, there are probably better ones that are not so hacky. Also using the KeepSubs service this way is probably not ethical. But this is only for educational purposes.

Comment: At first, I guess there are some security problems here related to cross-site http-requests issue. For example, I've just tried it and got `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://keepsubs.com/?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:34974' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Huh, that's odd, I tried it directly in the site by copy pasting the source into the console on the site. It worked then.

Comment: In your case it was a same-origin request, so it won't work for me) Thanks for try)