# When downloading captions from youtube I get 403

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm attempting to read captions from a youtube video but I keep getting 403 login required. When I provide an oauth token I get forbidden.

Why do I need authentication if all I'm doing is reading captions, something I can do if I visit youtube?

I can hack together something to pull them without going through the api, but I'd rather stay in Google's good books and abide by their tos.

There is a service called downsub.com which provides captions for all youtube videos, so I'm wondering if they are using youtube apis or something homebrew.

An example from the API explorer is this: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.captions.download?id=jMEVWVvrx_rd-FTZ2H4--MRAwNik5PAo6m3UYxQwdn4%253D&tfmt=srt&_h=1&

Comment: Some videos are not available and do not have autogenerated captions. A video must have atleast autogenerated subtitles to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46864428/how-do-some-sites-download-youtube-captions

Comment: That example I gave was for a video with automatically generated subs; it had them

Comment: The link to the other stack overflow isn't via their api

Comment: It's an unofficial API.  To answer your question. Yes to download captions using the API you need authentication. Downsubs does not use the Data api to do this. Downsubs uses the unofficial API.